# How to provide all ContextMenu logic in a separate class?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am trying to put all my ContextMenu logic in a separate class but it seems like I am not able to recognize in this class whether someone selects a item.

I have an application with a main activity. Next to some other things this activity contains a listview. This listview should contain a context menu, so I defined it corresponding to its Clicklistener:

```
MyListener myListener = new MyListener();

listview.setOnItemClickListener(myListener);
listview.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(myListener);
```

MyListener implements both OnItemClickListener and OnCreateContextMenuListener. I  did this to keep the class readable (like mentioned before there are already some other UI components and some logic). To this point everything works like a charm. Single clicks are recognized and also the ConextMenu is shown.

Now I also want that MyListener also reacts to the item that is selected inside the ContextMenu. Unfortunately only Activities and their corresponding SubClasses seem to provide a method like onContextItemSelected(menuItem item). So I would have to put that logic into my main activity and distribute my ContextMenu logic by doing this (I also tested this, it works, but distributing the logic seems to me like a no-go).

Do I miss here something? Is there a way to define some kind of a ContextMenu ClickListener for my listview in another way than putting it in my main activity? Or am I doing some bad practise without recognizing?

Looking forward to your opinions!

Cheers Eyeless

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution is to forward the clicks to your `MyListener` class.
Create a new method in your `MyListener` class. Ideally I would call it just like the original method:

`public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`
In this method you implement your logic.

Then make your `MyListener` variable a field of your `Activity`.
Now, just override `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` in your `Activity` and forward the clicks to your listener class:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {
    return myListener.onContextItemSelected( item );
}
```

Comment: Well sure, that would be possible. It just seems to me as there is a possibility to define foreign classes as listeners for single clicks and context clicks but no option to define what follows (imho a separate class for setting up a ContextMenu without the possibility to react on anything that happens inside this ContextMenu is quite useless). That's why I am asking whether I am doing something wrong or missing something. Thanks anyway!